# Problem using find with filenames containing spaces

Tags: text-processing, find, text

I'm trying to run join a bunch of files using the find command.

I have determined that filenames containing spaces are giving me a problem.

The following comand works for files that do not contain any spaces but fails when the filename contains a space.

```
  find /media/primary/acronis_ntfs/flickr_01/. -type f -name '*.*' | xargs cat > /media/primary/acronis_ntfs/flickr_01.txt
```

I have tried different commands as well - all with the same results.

```
  find /media/primary/acronis_ntfs/flickr_01/. -type f | xargs cat > /media/primary/acronis_ntfs/flickr_01.txt
```

If I go directly into the folder and run

```
  cat * > flickr_01.txt
```

It works - spaces and all.

I'm running ubuntu 16.10.

Any suggestions?

I'm losing my hair over something I thought is simple.

Comment: see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).. any particular reason you haven't accepted any of your 30 questions asked?

Comment: see also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697/why-is-looping-over-finds-output-bad-practice for usage of `-exec` option

Answer (score 3):

Make find use a NUL as the separator between filenames and tell xargs to look for same:

```
find .... -print0 | xargs -0 ...
```